# NSTimer crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in shared class

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` running in a shared class.  `+ (GlobalClass *)sharedInstance;`

Basically it runs once, and the second time it runs, it just killed the whole app.

This is how I'm doing the `NSTimer`

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(moveMe)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

method `moveMe` is just an empty method for now. So it shouldn't be something that's happening within `moveMe`.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: The timer you posted will run only once. So are you rescheduling it again? Also, is 'self' the singleton in this case? (in other words, is this timer created within a method in GlobalClass)

Comment: Hey Firoze, yes it's supposed to be repeats:YES. Forgot to change that, but it looks like hitting that moveMe function the first time killed it right away. Yes self is the singleton class. Thanks, Tee

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the colon in your selector name. The selector for `NSTimer` takes an `NSTimer` as an argument. Your code that creates the timer should look like this:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveMe:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:NO];
```

Note the colon after `moveMe`. Your method should then look something like this:

```
- (void)moveMe:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    // Code
}
```